# How to disable a button in a specified td using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This way i can hide the button on a td :

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(16)').hide();
```

But how to disable this button and keep showing it ? I tried prop and attr of jquery. Both dont work. Please  help if anybody knows.

Comment: could you provide a code of button inside of `td`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(16)').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(16) button').attr('disabled', true);
```

what about this? if you want to disable the button you need to select the button, not the td.